# ASP.Net textbox css class changing to "textbox" on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am having a strange issue when moving my ASP.Net code from my development VM to the server.

When the page loads on the VM I have some javascript in the Master that attaches a date time picker to textboxes

```
function loadAnyTimeDT() {
        $('.AnyTimeDT').each(function () {
            $(this).AnyTime_picker(
            {
                askEra: false,
                askSecond: false,
                format: "%d-%b-%y %H:%i"
            });
        });
        $('.AnyTimeD').each(function () {
            $(this).AnyTime_picker(
            {
                askEra: false,
                askSecond: false,
                format: "%d-%b-%y"
            });
        });
        $('.AnyTimeT').each(function () {
            $(this).AnyTime_picker(
            {
                askEra: false,
                askSecond: false,
                format: "%H:%i"
            });
        });          
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadAnyTimeDT();
    });
```

This was working great and I was happy with the results.  Move the code over to the server to deploy it and all of a sudden no date time pickers are working.

After inspecting the page source of the web page I noticed that the css class is being swapped to "textbox" on the server but not in the vm.  This is happening after the page loads not in the code.

Here is an example of one of the textboxes inside a gridview
    `<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbTimeStartTime" CssClass="AnyTimeT" runat="Server" Text="<%# Eval("StartTime") %>"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>`

After the page load this is what I see in the source
`<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTime$ctl03$txtbTimeStartTime" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTime_txtbTimeStartTime" class="textbox">`

This is making it hard to attach my date time pickers as I can no longer select just the correct ones by class.

Any thoughts on forcing the css class to stay as it does on the VM?

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you're using an `input type="text"` when `input type="date"` or any of the other date types would be more appropriate?

Comment: I am not, the input tag is generated from the asp:TextBox.  I am considering just using html input tags rather than the textbox's but I am still curious why the css class is changing.

Comment: After doing some further research and testing this seems to be stemming from a difference between visual studio 2010 and 2012.